# Can I use thicker wires or twisted pair for Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, wire, twisted-pair

I'm planning to use 2 types of connectors:

- A : GND + 24V + 100Mbps ethernet (4 wires) + 2 wires with various functions
- B : 1 Gbps ethernet with PoE (8 wires)

For type B, I found of the shelf connectors meeting my needs (small size + subssea,) but I haven't found any for type A that can handle at least 3A (ideally 5A) while also being rated for use with Ethernet (so I might need to have it custom made.)

Using 2 different connectors, one of which custom made, is quite sub-optimal. Is it possible to reliably do one of the 2 things below:

1. Use a single custom connector with 4 twisted pairs, with some pairs thick enough to carry 3 or 5A? (Either a single thin pair, or the 2 pairs not used for 100Mbps, or all pairs.) This way, I could use the same custom connector for everything.
2. Use non-twisted (and thicker) wires for the 100Mb connection, knowing that there will be up to 3 or 5A flowing next to them? Maximum length is 3m. This way, I could use only standard connectors (2 different models.)

NB: Reliability is very important to me. If it can't be done in a reliable way, I'd rather use 1 standard + 1 custom connector rather that take any risk (no security risk, but downtime costs >1k$/day, vs connectors about 200$.)

Comment: How will the thicker wires be impedance matched? How will using untwisted wires prevent serious cross-talk and interference suppression?

Comment: For the thick wires, withing each pair, they will be the same. If need be, I can ask the manufacturer to use the same thick wires for all pairs. For crosstalk and inteference in the solution 2, this is exactly why I'm asking about it instead of just doing it : for 1Gbps ethernet, I wouldn't even think about it. 100Mbps is more forgiving (slower signal, higher voltage levels) but I'm not sure if this will be enough to male it work.

Comment: Perhaps acceptable, perhaps not, but can you just use PoE on connector A as well, and regulate down to 24V on the user side?

Comment: @VladimirCravero : sadly no, on the other side, there are usually of the shelf devices : some support PoE, other require a separate supply. Adding an intermediate subssea enclosure just to convert PoE to 24V + ethernet would be far too expensive (and not very practical from a mechanical point of view)

Comment: I am not sure I understand @Sandro - if connector A is for off the shelf devices, what are those devices using? Just use the same connector they are using on both sides of the cable.

Comment: Most of the shelf devices come either with just a cable (and no connector at all), or with big connectors (often featuring a few other pins we don't need). The classic way to have ethernet + power is using 13 pin connectors with 4 twisted pairs for Ethernet and 5 thicker wires for power and other uses (like RS232). The problem is that those 13 pin connectors are far bigger, so if using them, I can't fit the number of connectors I want to put. 8 pin connectors exist in a far smaller form factor, but only in either 4 twisted pairs or 8 thick (5A max) cables : but the mix is not standard

Comment: _"100Mbps is more forgiving (slower signal, higher voltage levels)"_ - Not sure where you get that; 100BASE-TX uses _lower_ voltage levels (-1, 0, +1) than 1000BASE-T (-2, -1, 0, +1, +2). And both use the same symbol rate (125Msymbols/sec/lane). (And, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet#1000BASE-T) they're also supposed to have the same noise immunity; not sure how that pans out in practice though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't want to try 100MBit Ethernet over non-twisted wires.  If reliability is crucial, use proper cables.

For me, that means that your option 2 is out.  Ethernet needs proper cables.  100MBit wiring is less picky than 1GBit, but even so there are limits to what it will accept.

I'd go with standard Ethernet cables and connectors and a separate power cable and connectors.  If there's some horribly important reason why two cables are not acceptable, then I'd go with option 1.

---

There was a building I worked in where they pulled too many Ethernet cables through a slightly too small hole in a concrete foundation.  Some of the wires lost their proper twist while being forced through the hole.

The computers on those connections had really poor Ethernet.

A cheap Ethernet cable tester couldn't tell the difference - it said things were fine.  It was only checking continuity, though.

A far more expensive cable tester that checked impedance and losses and crosstalk rejected those cables - that agreed with the absolutely crummy network performance of the affected PCs.

Comment: So solution 2 is probably out (even if length is much sorter than in your case)

Answer (score 0):

It is worth considering the [Amphenol X-Lok connectors](https://amphenolltw.com/product-info/X-Lok/X-Lok.StandardSize).

[image]

(Picture from Amphenol datasheet.)

They comes in a variety of sizes, and the ["mini"](https://amphenolltw.com/product-info/X-Lok/X-Lok.MiniSize) size is rated for 5A/contact if just 2 of the contacts are in use.

There are also [adapters](https://docs.rs-online.com/46a0/A700000007556681.pdf) which convert to standard RJ45, and the whole assemble is rated for CAT5e/Gigabit operation.

22AWG UTP CAT5e cables are fairly widely available for just this kind of power over data applications, and depending on environment two cores should be good at 5A.  [Here's](https://hubbellcdn.com/specsheet/PREMISE_C5ELPRW_spec.pdf) a link to an example from Hubbell.  There are also a more limited range of 20AWG UTP cables.